# Upload templates in Azure using API or SDK

Tags: azure, rest, templates, go, sdk

I am looking to upload a VM deployment template in Azure programmatically either using Go SDK or Rest API. I am not able to find the correct documentation for the same.

Also, I don't want to start VM deployment. It's restricted to uploading the deployment template to the Azure.

[image]

Comment: define - uploading the template? there is no action of uploading the template in the api as far as i know

Comment: @4c74356b41 I have created a VM and exported its template. Similarly, I should be able to upload the template in Templates section of the Azure.?  Updated Screenshot as well.

Answer (score 1):

Well, here's the sample api request to put the empty template to the portal:

```
{
    "name": "test",
    "type": "Microsoft.Gallery/myareas/galleryitems",
    "properties": {
        "publisherName": "username_goes_here",
        "publisherDisplayName": "username_goes_here",
        "displayName": "test",
        "description": "test",
        "artifacts": {
            "default": {
                "name": "template",
                "type": "template",
                "uri": "https://gallery.azure.com/artifact/20161101/Microsoft.MyGallery.0.0.9-preview/DeploymentTemplates/EmptyTemplate.json"
            }
        },
        "images": [
            {
                "context": "ibiza",
                "items": [
                    {
                        "name": "large",
                        "type": "icon",
                        "uri": "https://gallery.azure.com/GalleryRp/Content/GalleryItemDefaultLargeIcon.png"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "version": "1.0.0",
        "uiDefinitionUri": "",
        "publishingState": "stable",
        "categoryIds": [],
        "links": []
    }
}
```

PUT: https://management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Gallery/myareas/df010a79-26a3-401a-8697-a5736c82895a/galleryItems/test?api-version=2016-03-01-preview

not sure where to get the guid from, probably have to create first one by hand or maybe the get request to myareas will show list of possible areas

Unfortunately, I dont see this documented in the API anywhere.

EDIT: I was able to find the list of operations for the provider:

```
{
    "namespace": "Microsoft.Gallery",
    "resourceTypes": [
        {
            "resourceType": "myareas",
            "locations": "",
            "apiVersions": "2016-03-01-preview",
            "capabilities": "None"
        },
        {
            "resourceType": "myareas/areas",
            "locations": "",
            "apiVersions": "2016-03-01-preview",
            "capabilities": "None"
        },
        {
            "resourceType": "myareas/areas/areas",
            "locations": "",
            "apiVersions": "2016-03-01-preview",
            "capabilities": "None"
        },
        {
            "resourceType": "myareas/galleryitems",
            "locations": "",
            "apiVersions": "2016-03-01-preview",
            "capabilities": "None"
        },
        {
            "resourceType": "myareas/areas/galleryitems",
            "locations": "",
            "apiVersions": "2016-03-01-preview",
            "capabilities": "None"
        },
        {
            "resourceType": "myareas/areas/areas/galleryitems",
            "locations": "",
            "apiVersions": "2016-03-01-preview",
            "capabilities": "None"
        },
        {
            "resourceType": "enroll",
            "locations": "",
            "apiVersions": "2016-03-01-preview",
            "capabilities": "None"
        },
        {
            "resourceType": "register",
            "locations": "",
            "apiVersions": "2016-03-01-preview",
            "capabilities": "None"
        },
        {
            "resourceType": "galleryitems",
            "locations": "",
            "apiVersions": "2016-03-01-preview 2014-04-01-preview",
            "capabilities": "None"
        },
        {
            "resourceType": "resources",
            "locations": "",
            "apiVersions": "2016-03-01-preview 2014-04-01-preview",
            "capabilities": "None"
        },
        {
            "resourceType": "retrieveresourcesbyid",
            "locations": "",
            "apiVersions": "2016-03-01-preview 2014-04-01-preview",
            "capabilities": "None"
        },
        {
            "resourceType": "generateartifactaccessuri",
            "locations": "",
            "apiVersions": "2016-03-01-preview",
            "capabilities": "None"
        },
        {
            "resourceType": "checknameavailability",
            "locations": "",
            "apiVersions": "2016-03-01-preview",
            "capabilities": "None"
        }
    ]
}
```

So I dont think it a UI proxy. its seems to be a real provider, but it seems to sit on the tenant level or something? Notice the url: `https://management.azure.com/providers`.

EDIT: Yeah, I can get the list of my areas with this call: `https://management.azure.com/providers/microsoft.gallery/myareas/?api-version=2020-01-01`

and it would return my only area so far: df010a79-26a3-401a-8697-a5736c82895a

Comment: I got this as well from inspecting the network call. But this may be UI proxy. Yes, I don't see any documentation.

Comment: hm, interesing, i dont see such a provider at all. anywhere. in api reference, in the portal provider list, in powershell. but I do see this, for instance: https://github.com/tfitzmac/resource-capabilities/blob/master/complete-mode-deletion.csv